# What is the material that is present in all the 12 Jyotirlingas that we have?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

What is the material composition that is present in all the 12 Jyotirlingas that we have?
Across the globe we see Shivalingas appearing don't we consider any of them as Jyotirlingas?

Was there any study or literature present for the same?

Comment: why would the physical substance that the jyotirlinga us composed of determine its designation as a Jyotirlinga??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most essential "composition material" of a Jyotirliṅga is said to be the presence of God Shiva-Shakti themselves, in the said liṅgam.

Also, the twelve Jyotirliṅgas do not constitute an exhaustive list, but only the most popular ones found on Earth out of the 64 well-known ones; however, there are still many Jyotirliṅgas, on Earth, and various other *lokas* too, as discussed [in Shiva Purana Verse 8.1.18-19](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc398239.html).

Now, talking about the composition,

In the material outfit, the composition can be varying.

For instance, the Original Someśvara liṅgam was made from Earthen mud (Parthiva).

> [Verse 8.14.36-37](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226515.html#note-t-88879), Shiva Purana
>
> गृहीत्वा ते ततश्चन्द्रं दक्षं चाश्वास्य निर्जराः । प्रभासे
> ऋषयश्चक्रुस्तत्र गत्वाखिलाश्च वै ॥ ३६ ॥
>  आवाह्य तीर्थवर्याणि
> सरस्वत्यादिकानि च । **पार्थिवेन** तदा पूजां मृत्युञ्जयविधानतः ॥ ३७ ॥
>
> > - 36-37. The gods and the sages consoled Dakṣa and took the moon to
> >   Prabhāsa. They invoked the sacred waters of Sarasvatī and other
> >   rivers and **performed the worship of the earthen lingam** in
> >   accordance with the Mṛtyuñjaya rites.

The other Jyotirliṅgas too, have been called "earthen (parthiva)", in the Shiva Purāṇa. With two exceptions - Vaidyanātheśvara and Kāśī-Viśveśvara.

- We have references saying Vaidyanath Jyotirliṅga to be made from the essence of Vajra.

> [Verse 8.28.19b](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226529.html), Shiva Purāṇa
>
> तत्रैव तत्स्थितं लिंगं **वज्रसारसमुद्भवम्** ।
>
> > The (Vaidyanātheśvara) *liṅga* **made of the essence of diamond (vajra)** remained fixed
> > there.

- Similarly, for the Kāśī-Viśveśvara Jyotirliṅgam, as per the Shiva Purāṇa [Verse 8.22.19-25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226523.html), it is said to be made by Shiva Himself, and it is not destroyed even in KalpAnta pralaya, occurring at the end of the day of god Brahmâ. The composition is unknown, since this is the most mysterious.

**Overall**, almost all the 12 Jyotirliṅgam were made from sacred Earthen mud (*Parthiva - liṅgam*) by the respective bhaktas.

Answer (score 1):

```
Across the globe we see Shivalingas appearing don't we consider any of them as Jyotirlingas?
```

The answer was given already in Shiv Puran,

> 14. O excellent ones, the three worlds consisting of the gods, Asuras and human beings are pervaded by Śiva in the form of phallic image for the welfare of the worlds.
> 15. In order to bless the worlds, lord Śiva assumes different phallic forms here in the holy centres as well as in other places.
> 16. **Śiva incarnates in those places wherever he is devoutly remembered by the devotees. After carrying out their task he stations himself there.**
> 17. He has assigned his phallic form for the benefit of the worlds. The devotee attains perfection by worshipping that form.

Thus, we know that firstly the Parthiv Linga must established by his devotees, and then he appears there by himself and blesses devotees with desires & thus become Jyotirling. Thus saying the llingams were only established in Bharatvarsh. Where Shiv appeared to his devotees.

```
What is the material composition that is present in all the 12 Jyotirlingas that we have?
```

Shiv Puran, Section 4 - Koṭirudra-Saṃhitā

Chapter 14 - The origin of the Jyotirliṅga **Somanātha**

> 36-37. The gods and the sages consoled Dakṣa and took the moon to Prabhāsa.[1]They invoked the sacred waters of Sarasvatī and other rivers and performed the worship of the **earthen phallic image** in accordance with the Mṛtyuñjaya rites.

Chapter 15 - The origin of the Second **Mallikārjuna** Jyotirliṅga

> 19. From that day onwards: that phallic image of Śiva born of Mallikārjuna became famous in the three worlds.

(For Mallikārjuna Lingam nothing is mentioned whether it was a Parthiv lingam or not)

Chapter 16 - The greatness of the Jyotirliṅga **Mahākāla**

> 4-35. Emboldened thus they performed the worship of **Śiva’ś earthern idol**. They sat firmly engaged in meditation. On seeing them thus the mighty Dūṣāṇa shouted “Let them be killed. Let them be bound.” But the brahmins, the sons of Vedapriya engrossed in meditation on Śiva did not hear the shouts.

Chapter 18 - The greatness of the Jyotirliṅga **Oṃkāreśvara**.

> With great pleasure he went to the place where Oṃkāra himself was present. There he made an **earthen idol of Śiva**.

Chapter 19 - The greatness of the Jyotirliṅga **Kedāreśvara**

> 2. Requested by them for their worship, Śiva, being subservient to the devotees comes every day to that **earthen phallic image of Śiva**.

Chapter 20 - The greatness of the Jyotirliṅga **Bhīmeśvara**

> 41. There the captive monarch made an excellent **earthen idol of Śiva** and started its worship with a desire for pleasant results.

Chapter 23 - The greatness of the Jyotirliṅga **Kāśī-Viśveśvara**

> अविमुक्तं **स्वयं लिंगं** स्थापितं परमात्मना ।
> न कदाचित्त्वया त्याज्यमिदं क्षेत्रं ममांशक ॥ २१ ॥
> 21. The phallic image Avimukta is **installed by the great Śiva himself**. O you born of my parts, this holy centre should never be abandoned by you.”

(Kasi Vishveshwar lingam is the Swayambhu linga)

**Tryambakeśvara**
Chapter 25 - The planned arrangement of Gautama

> 57. After saying this and circumambulating the mountain, the excellent sage made **earthen phallic images** of Śiva and worshipped them.

Chapter 28 - The glory of the Jyotirliṅga **Vaidyanātheśvara**

> 19-21. He was distressed by its heavy weight. He placed it on the ground. The phallic image made of the **essence of diamond** remained fixed there. O sage, that phallic image is known as Vaidyanātheśvara. It yields all desires and dispels sins at its very sight. It is famous in the three worlds. It grants worldly pleasures here and salvation hereafter.
> 42-43. I then became angry. I dug a ditch in the ground and kindled fire. I made **earthen idols**. By waving lights in the course of worship I worshipped Śiva with scents, sandal paste, incense and food-offerings.

(Now this is confusing as either the Vaidyanāth lingam was Parthiv or made up of Daimond. As it mentions both.)

**Nageshwar**
Chapter 29 - The havoc of the Rākṣasas of Dārukāvana

> 48. O great sages, the direct worship of Śiva was performed by the leader then in accordance with the rites of worshipping the **earthen phallic image.**

Chapter 31 - The greatness of **Rāmeśvara**

> 21. After saying this, he drank water and then performed the worship of **Śiva’s earthen image**.

Chapter 33 - Origin and glory of the Jyolirliṅga **Ghuśmeśvara**

> 30. Taking the day’s earthly phallic images she went towards the bank of the lake repeating the names of Śiva, maintaining the normalcy of her mind as afore.
> 31. When she cast off the **earthen phallic images** and returned she saw her son standing on the bank of the lake.

(Thus we conclude that Jyotirlingams arose from Parthiv lingas as mentioned by Suta in Shiv Puran.)

**कलिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Comment: there is also a crytal like linga at rameshwaram installed by mother sita herself, showing only in the morning

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Actually the original Ramanathswamy Jyotirlinga is the one which was made by Seeta devi from sand. The other linga is Vishwalinga(the one you mentioned which os shown on Morning), it was actually brought by Hanuman from kailasha.(So, to say Srī Rām just consecrated the lingams but didn't made one by his own.) As per legend the puja is first ofered to Vishwalinga and to Ramanathswamy Jyotirling as per the boon and rule laid by Śrī Rām himself.